# Firestore: send notification to specific device using cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a function that runs every minute checking something and if it's true it sends a notification to that specific user's device. The problem is that I don't know how to send to that user only:

```js
export const remindEvents = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("* * * * *").onRun(() => {
        const querySnapshot = await db
            .collectionGroup('leases')
            .where(
                'frequency',
                isEqualTo: 'testing',
            )
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) {
                for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
                    // HERE I TAKE THE DOCS I NEED OK

                    // send notification
                    const token = querySnapshot.data()!.token;

                    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: "New notification!",
                            body: `you just got a notification`,
                            icon: "your-icon-url",
                            click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                        },
                    };

                    // THIS IS WHAT I'M NOT SURE ABOUT
                    // return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
                }
            });
    });
```

Here I have another working example but in this case when a document is created in a collection:

```
export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
    .document("orders/{orderId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
      const order = snapshot.data();

      const querySnapshot = await db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(order.seller)
          .get();

      const token = querySnapshot.data()!.token;

      const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
        notification: {
          title: "New Order!",
          body: `you sold a ${order.product} for ${order.total}`,
          icon: "your-icon-url",
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        },
      };

      return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
    });
```

How would I extract the first `sendToDevice` to point directly to the user I need having the cloud function instead?

Using Flutter for the app.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet you'll need to some how know the token(s) of the device(s) to send the message to. Since you talk about a specific user, you'll need to somehow look up the device token(s) for that user.

The common way to do this is to keep a mapping in your database of the device token(s) for each user. You add tokens to this database when you [monitor the token generation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation) on the client. You remove tokens from your database when FCM tells you they are no longer in use, as shown in this sample project [performing token cleanup](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L87-L108).

Comment: How can I monitor that using Flutter? And why would I have to remove the token manually? That was something I didn't have to do until now. I was just using querySnapshot.data()!.token to get it and forgot about update/remove it. Is that wrong then?

Comment: To get the token on Flutter, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client#access_the_registration_token . You have to remove expired tokens as otherwise your token database will just keep growing and growing over time. If you're new to this, have a look at this article too: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-is-fcm-aggregated-delivery-data-d6d68396b83b